# How to add XML attribute in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs

I created this XML using ExtJs:

```
<Entity><Fields><Field><value>1777</value></Field><id></id></Fields></Entity>
```

Using Ext.data.writer.XmlView source.

my question is - What do I need to do in order to add XML attribute to one of the fields?
For instance:

> < Field **name=”request-id”** >

Just for reference, that's the codef I used to write the XML in ExtJS:

```
   var proxy1 = new Ext.data.proxy.Rest({

        url : url,
        pageParam: undefined,
        limitParam: undefined,
        sortParam: undefined,
        startParam: undefined,
        noCache: false,
        appendId: false,        
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'entities'
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        },
        actionMethods: {
            read: "POST"
        },
        writer: {
            writeRecordId: false,
            type: 'xml',
            nameProperty: 'mapping',
            writeAllFields: true,
            documentRoot: "Entity",
            record: "Fields"
        }


    });

var model = Ext.define('Entity', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
     {name: 'Field', type: 'string'}

    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: proxy1,
    model: 'Entity',
    data : [
        {'Field': '<value>1777</value>' }
    ]



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the code of the XML writer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Xml2.html#Ext-data-writer-Xml-method-writeRecords), it seems like there's nothing you can do to achieve this with the standard XML writer. You'll have to extend or override its `writeRecord` method.

Here's, for example, how you could do it:

```
Ext.define('AttributeAwareXmlWriter', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.writer.Xml'

    ,alias: 'writer.aaxml'

    ,writeRecords: function (request, data) {
        var me = this,
            xml = [],
            i = 0,
            len = data.length,
            root = me.documentRoot,
            record = me.record,
            recordAttributes = me.recordAttributes,
            needsRoot = data.length !== 1,
            item,
            key;

        // may not exist
        xml.push(me.header || '');

        if (!root && needsRoot) {
            root = me.defaultDocumentRoot;
        }

        if (root) {
            xml.push('<', root, '>');
        }

        for (; i < len; ++i) {
            item = data[i];
            xml.push('<', record);
            if (recordAttributes) {
                for (key in recordAttributes) {
                    xml.push(' ', key, '="', recordAttributes[key], '"');
                }
            }
            xml.push('>');
            for (key in item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    xml.push('<', key, '>', item[key], '</', key, '>');
                }
            }
            xml.push('</', record, '>');
        }

        if (root) {
            xml.push('</', root, '>');
        }

        request.xmlData = xml.join('');
        return request;
    }
});
```

After including such a class, you could use the following writer:

```
    writer: {
        writeRecordId: false,
        type: 'aaxml', // changed to custom type
        nameProperty: 'mapping',
        writeAllFields: true,
        documentRoot: "Entity",
        record: "Fields",
        recordAttributes: {
            name: 'request-id'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. it prints me an XML attribute ! the only thing that differ is that the attribute was printed on "Fields" and not on "Field". but I fixed this with the override function. thanks!